# On Ajax submit, vars added in preprocess are lost

Tags: 8, ajax

I'm currently working on a D8 project and I'm displaying a node edit form in a block. I use template_preprocess_table in order to pass some parameters to my 
theme but when I submit the form using ajax the form is reloaded and the parameters are lost so I don't get the correct form format.

Update:

In my MYTHEME.theme file:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_table(&$variables) {

  if($variables['attributes']['id'] == 'field-completion-milestones-values'){
    $element = $variables['rows'];
    foreach( $element as $key => $milestones){
      $completion_milestone = $milestones['cells'][1]['content'];

      if(isset($completion_milestone['field_milestone'])){

        $milestone_id = $completion_milestone['field_milestone']['widget']['#default_value'][0];
        $default_completion_milestone = array('name' => $milestone_id);
        $type_id = milestoneGetTypeId($default_completion_milestone);
        if($type_id == 156) {//Milestones with links - create button
          $variables['rows'][$key]['cells'][1]['content']['test_button'] = TRUE;
        }
        else if($type_id == 155){//Milestones with upload document button
          $variables['rows'][$key]['cells'][1]['content']['test_upload'] = TRUE;
        }
        else if($type_id == 154){//Milestones without link or upload buttons
          $variables['rows'][$key]['cells'][1]['content']['test_plain'] = TRUE;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And in my table.html.twig file:

```
{% set milestone_id = cell.content.field_milestone['widget']['#default_value'][0] %}
{% if(milestone_id) %}
    <div class="delivery__completed-milestones__field">
      <label>{{ cell.content.field_milestone['widget']['#options'][milestone_id] }}</label>
        <span class="status-marker delayed">D</span>
        {% if cell.content.field_tip['widget'][0]['value']['#default_value'] %}
            <span class="custom-tooltip"><span title="{{ cell.content.field_tip['widget'][0]['value']['#default_value'] }}">?</span></span>
        {% endif %}
        {% if cell.content.test_button %}
             {% set custom_url = cell.content.field_url['widget'][0]['uri']['#default_value'] %}
             {% if cell.content.field_url['widget'][0]['title']['#default_value'] %}
                 {% set link_text = cell.content.field_url['widget'][0]['title']['#default_value'] %}
             {% else %}
                 {% set link_text = cell.content.field_url['widget'][0]['uri']['#default_value'] %}
             {% endif %}
             <a class="button" href ="{{ custom_url }}">{{ link_text }}</a>
        {% endif %}
        {% if cell.content.test_upload %}
             {{ cell.content.field_milestone_completion_up }}
        {% endif %}
        <div class="hidden">
           {{ cell.content.field_delivery_status }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

My form submit function:

```
public static function ajaxFormEntityFormSubmit($form, &$form_state) {
    $entity = $form_state->getBuildInfo()['callback_object']->getEntity();

    // Clear user input.
    $input = $form_state->getUserInput();
    // We should not clear the system items from the user input.
    $clean_keys = $form_state->getCleanValueKeys();
    $clean_keys[] = 'ajax_page_state';
    foreach ($input as $key => $item) {
      if (!in_array($key, $clean_keys) && substr($key, 0, 1) !== '_') {
        unset($input[$key]);
      }
    }

    // Store new entity for display in the AJAX callback.
    $input['entity'] = $entity;
    $form_state->setUserInput($input);

    // Rebuild the form state values.
    $form_state->setRebuild();
    $form_state->setStorage([]);
  }
```

And my callback:

```
public static function ajaxFormEntityCallback(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // If errors, returns the form with errors and messages.
    if ($form_state->hasAnyErrors()) {
      return $form;
    }
    // Else show the result.
    else {
      $userInputs = $form_state->getUserInput();
      $entity = $userInputs['entity'];
      $entity_type = $entity->getEntityTypeId();
      $configurations = $form_state->getValue('ajax_form_entity');

      $response = new AjaxResponse();

      // Get messages even if not shown.
      $status_messages = array('#type' => 'status_messages');
      $message = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($status_messages);

      // Reload the form.
        $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand($configurations['form_selector'], $form));

      return $response;
    }
  }
```

In my hook_form_alter :

```
    $form['#attributes']['class'][] = $ajax_id;
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'Drupal\MY_MODULE\Plugin\Form\FormAlter::ajaxFormEntityFormSubmit';
    $form['actions']['submit']['#ajax'] = array(
      'callback' => 'Drupal\MY_MODULE\Plugin\Form\FormAlter::ajaxFormEntityCallback',
      'wrapper' => $ajax_id,
      'effect' => 'fade',
    );
    $form['ajax_form_entity'] = [
      '#type' => 'hidden',
      '#value' => [
        'reload' => '.reload',
        'form_selector' => '.' . $ajax_id,
        'show_message' => TRUE,
      ]
    ];
```

What I'm doing is to show/hide fields from a field collection field based on a taxonomy term value. Maybe this is not the best solution but I didn't find any other way to solve my problem.

Is it possible to store those vars somehow after ajax submit?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Paste the whole code, this is not enough information to give nay advice.

Comment: The AJAX are in the form? Which extends FormBase? Something seems off here.

Comment: @Kevin what do you mean? This code works fine for the rest of my forms but when it reloads the form with those hidden fields I have the problem. I  guess that it has to do with the prepossessing as seems like the vars I set are empty when the form reloads.

Comment: @Kevin the form is not just a custom form but a node edit form placed in a custom block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this without using template_preprocess_table. Instead I used created a custom module where I extend the twig in oder to have access to a function in my PHP. In my Twig I call that function and I get as a return the values so as I can display properly the fields needed.